# Add leading zero to months

Tags: mysql, date

This is a sample of my OrderDate column, and I am trying to convert it from "text" type to "date" type.
I believe first I need to add the missing leading zeros to some months (first row, for example).

| OrderDate |
| --- |
| 29-8-2016 |
| 25-12-2018 |
| 22-11-2015 |
| -------- |

How can I add the leading zero missing in some months ?

Comment: ```SELECT STR_TO_DATE(OrderDate, '%e-%c-%Y') AS OrderDate, ...```

Comment: It did work, although some fields from that column became null... Do you have any idea why?

Comment: *some fields from that column became null...* Either these rows values does not match the pattern DD-MM-YYYY (for example, they stores YYYY-MM-DD) or they stores invalid data value (for example 30-2-2022). See `SHOW WARNINGS;`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Yes, I can see some rows have different patterns, for example, MM-DD-YYYY.
Can I do something about it?

Comment: The value may produce correct output for both DD-MM-YYYY and MM-DD-YYYY, and you cannt determine what pattern must be applied to such value.